# How to create an Outlook 2010 filter that handle mails with a specific message header?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I would like to let Outlook 2010 (in combination with Exchange 2010) move my incomming e-mails containing "foobar" in a message header into an subfolder.

Here some examples how it looks like:

- Message-ID: foobar
- Message-ID: 123@foobar
- Message-ID: <123@foobar>
- Message-ID: <123@foobar-test>

All those messages have to be moved into an subfolder.

I tried the following settings but they don't work:

```
After receiving an message
with Message-ID: *foobar* in the message headers
move those messages into folder foobar
do not apply any other filters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook does not support wildcards to be used in rules searching for specific words, except withing email addresses. So simplify it by just using just "foobar". This will cause the rule to run on any message with "foobar" anywhere in the header.

[image]